# Using wp_enqueue_script on scripts that contain PHP

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-register-script

I'm am working on a WooCommerce website, and have all my jQuery in the footer inside script tags. I use PHP to filter out the needed scripts for any particular page.

However, I would like to use the suggested method of using wp_enqueue_script to load my jquery. The trouble is that scripts containing PHP wont work unless I pass any PHP variables to he script using `wp_localize_script`, which works.... mostly.

I call the enqueue in my functions.php using the wp_enqueue_scripts hook, but some of the PHP variables are not available when I register the script. Some global variables are, but some of my custom variables that are defined further down the line are empty when I try to access them via `localize_script`.

I'm hoping this makes some sense? If so, how would I go about doing this properly?

For example, let's say some PHP variables are defined in a particular page template. These variables won't be accessible if I enqueue a script using the hook mentioned above. How can I enqueue a script that has access to all the PHP variables defined on the page?

The actual code is a bit complex so ill try to simplify:-

In my functions.php I have the following:-

```
function wp_enqueue_woocommerce_style(){

    $array = array(
        "var1" => <?php echo $var1 ?>,
        "var2" => <?php echo $var2 ?>
      );

    wp_register_script('chroma_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/chroma.js', '', '1.1', TRUE);
    wp_enqueue_script('chroma_js');
    wp_localize_script( "chroma_js", "php_vars", $array);

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_enqueue_woocommerce_style',99 );
```

Which enqueues my script to the footer. However, the 2 PHP variables are defined in the function I hook into 'woocommerce_before_single_product'. When I try to access var1 & var2 in my script they are not defined. Any PHP variables already defined when I call the enqueue work fine. So, im not sure how to go about passing these variables to an enqueued script.

Comment: You need to pass PHP variables via [`wp_localize_script()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) to JS scripts

Comment: Thanks Peiter. Yes, you are right. I wrote the above post wrong. I am using localize_script and having the problems. Ive edited the above post to avoid further confusion.

Comment: you get null because your script load before you php variable.If you want to check just define it and check

Comment: I understand Vasim. Thats essentially my question. How can I use enqueue_script and still have access to my variables? Simply putting the wp_enqueue_scripts into the footer, *after* all the variables have been defined, doesnt work. It only seems to work when I put the enqueue in my functions file. But at that stage the variables are not defined. Hence my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're outputting the script in the footer, you can call `wp_localize_script` at any point after your script is enqueued but before the script is output on `wp_footer` priority 20.

```
function wp_enqueue_woocommerce_style(){
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'chroma_js',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/chroma.js',
        '',
        '1.1',
        true
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_enqueue_woocommerce_style' );

function wp_localize_woocommerce_style(){
    $array = array(
        'var1' => $var1,
        'var2' => $var2
    );
    wp_localize_script( 'chroma_js', 'php_vars', $array );
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'wp_localize_woocommerce_style', 0 );
```

Comment: This looks promising. I didn't consider calling the enqueue and localize at different locations. So, basically, if a PHP variable has been defined before wp_localize_woocommerce_style is hooked in, it'll be available to the enqueued script, correct? And to be clear, both these functions still go in functions.php, right?

Comment: yes, you'll be able to access data defined between when the script is enqueued at `wp_enqueue_scripts` and when it's output in `wp_footer`. both go in `functions.php`.

Comment: That sounds perfect. Thanks Milo. I cant try this yet as im tangled up in something else, but im going to give it a go and report back asap.

Comment: Gave it a go Milo. Worked a treat. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

// Register the script
wp_register_script( 'some_handle', 'path/to/myscript.js' );

// Localize the script with new data
$translation_array = array(
    'some_string' => __( 'Some string to translate', 'plugin-domain' ),
    'a_value' => '10'
);
wp_localize_script( 'some_handle', 'object_name', $translation_array );

// Enqueued script with localized data.
wp_enqueue_script( 'some_handle' );
```

You can access the variables in JavaScript as follows:

```
<script>
// alerts 'Some string to translate'
alert( object_name.some_string);
</script> 
Note: The data in the resulting JavaScript call will be passed as text (see ticket #25280). If you are trying to pass integers you will need to call the JavaScript parseInt() function.

<script>
// Call a function that needs an int.
FinalZoom = map.getBoundsZoomLevel( bounds ) - parseInt( object_name.a_value, 10 ); 
</script>
```

Comment: I dont have any problems running the right scripts on the right pages. Its more a case of PHP variables not being available. For example: I have a PHP function action hooked into 'woocommerce_before_single_product' which defines some key PHP variables.  I then want these variables available in my enqueued script. The enqueue and register calls are hooked into "wp_enqueue_scripts" as in your example. But if I try to pass the variables I defined using register_script, they come through as null. It seems the variables are not yet defined when I call enqueue.

Comment: What actually your code i did  not get you

Comment: Can you write down your code snippet here

Comment: Very sorry Vasim. I got my terms wrong. I am using "localize_script" to pass the variables. Ive edited my original post accordingly and added a code snippet.

Comment: okay,I am enthusiastic to learn wp.

Comment: If solved then mark it out.

Comment: Not solved. Still the original issue. I just wrote the original post wrong. Ive corrected it now.

Comment: If i am going right way you need to access you function.php variable into your page

Answer (score 0):

I'm used this code recently to get variable in header image path.Add this function to your functions.php:

```
function img()
{
    return get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/img/';
}
```

and use this in your header.php like this:

```
<img src="<?php echo img(); ?>my-image.jpg">
```